# Reading multiple csv files with different columns and rows into separate dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, directory

There are 500+ csv files in a /data folder, each with different columns and rows (but a unique ID is available, they are cohort data).

I wanted to apply the 'read.csv' function to individual csv files in the following manner:

```
df <- 
  list.files(path = "/data", pattern = ".csv")   

    as1_01 <- read.csv(file = 'data/as1_01_examinee.csv')
    head(as1_01)
    
    as1_02 <- read.csv(file = 'data/as1_02_gen.csv')
    head(as1_02)
    
    as1_06<- read.csv(file = 'data/as1_06_disease.csv')
    head(as1_06)
```

but somehow R recognizes only `as1_01`, as having 5 columns and expects the following `as1_02` ... `as1_06` to have identical data structures (which they are NOT).

1. how to I tell R that data structures are different for different files? and read as separate dataframes?
2. (I will look more) and preferably, how can I make it using for loop and substr? I want to name the dataframe as having the first 5 characters ex) as1_02_gen.csv = as1_02

Comment: Try `flnames<-list.files(path = "/data", pattern = "\\.csv", full.names=TRUE); df_list<-lapply(flnames, read.csv)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
flnames <- list.files(path = "/data", pattern = "\\.csv", full.names=TRUE)  
df_list <- lapply(flnames, read.csv)
```

did the job! Thanks to @Rui Barradas

If you want to do it in a nested list way,

```r
data_dir <- "C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as"
num_fu <- 1 : 9
dirs <- paste0(data_dir, num_fu)

flnames <- lapply(dirs, list.files, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
as_list <- lapply(flnames, lapply, read.csv)
```

Using `lapply` *twice*.